# SQL Service Broker vs Custom Queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a mass mailer application, where a web application sets up a email template and then queues a bunch of email address for sending. The other side will be a Windows service (or exe) that will poll this queue, picking up the messages for sending.

My question is, what would the advantage be of using SQL Service Broker (or MSMQ) over just creating my own custom queue table?

Everything I'm reading is suggesting I use Service Broker, but I really don't see what the huge advantage over a flat table (that would be a lot simpler to work with for me). For reference the application will be used to send 50,000-100,000 emails almost daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you every need to port to another vendor's database, you will have less problem if you used normal tables.

As you seem to only have one reader and one write from your queue, I would tend to use a standard table until you hit problem.    However if you start to feel the need to use “locking hints” etc, that the time to switch to the Service Broker Queues.

I would not use MSMQ, if both the sender and the reader need a database connection to work.  MSMQ would be good if the sender did not talk to the database at all, as it lets the sender keep working when the database is down.   However having to setup and maintain both the MSMQ and the database is likely to be more work then it is worth for most systems.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll (very carefully) trial it with a flat table and see how it performs as this will be the quickest to implement. If I find that it's not up to scratch I'll switch over to Service Broker.

Answer (score 15):

Do you *know* how to implement a queue over a flat table? This is not a silly question, implementing a queue over a table correctly is much harder than it sounds. Queue-like-tables are notoriously deadlock prone and you need to carefully consider the table design and the enqueue and dequeue operations. Also, do you know how to scale your pooling of the table? And how are you goind to handle retries and timeouts (ie. what [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) are used for)?

I'm not saying you should use SSB. The lerning curve is *very* steep and is primarily a distributed applicaiton platform, not a local queueing product so some features, like dialogs, will actually be obstacles for you rather than advantages. I'm just saying that you must consider also the difficulties of flat-table-queues. If you never implemented a flat-table-queue then be warned, there are many dragons under that bridge.

50k-100k messages per *day* is nothing, is only one message per second. If you want 100k per *minute*, then we have something to talk about.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I knew I would have a lot to deal with whichever route I took. Do you have articles or sample applications that could get me pointed in the right direction? Everywhere I search I just keep getting more questions and less sure of what I'm doing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I had searched myself for such articles in the past at most reliable sources (MVP blogs, sqlserverpedia, sqlmag etc etc) but couldn't find a good sum up article. Some advice I have from my own experience: steer clear of anything fancy (like priorities) just try to get the FIFO enqueue/dequeue right (no blocking and deadlock free). Also make sure you use the queue for *events*, not for state. Ie. enqueue the 'request to send this email', not the email itself.

Comment: Service buses like Rebus or NServiceBus have SqlTransport which is implementation of queue on a table

Comment: @RemusRusanu do you consider this answer to be still valid given your post [Using tables as queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: I'd be more interested in point out that if you just want to use a SSB queue as a simple queue you can just reuse the same conversation for every message and just never issue an end conversation.  It will work find, be pretty darn fast and it's still integrated into your database.  (And internal/external activation is awesome.)

Answer (score 2):

For advantages of Service Broker see this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166063.aspx

In general we try to use a tool or standard functionality rather than building things ourselves. This lowers the cost and can make upgrading easier.

Comment: Thanks, I have already read that article. My question is, in my case are those advantages listed enough to out way the extra learning curve and complexity.

My custom table would be very simple and it would basically come down to 3 statements.
Pseudocode:
INSERT INTO Queue

SELECT * FROM Queue WHERE Completed = false
UPDATE Queue SET Completed = true

Comment: Without service broker you have to watch out for threading. Based on your code what will happen if new rows are added after the select but before the update. If your code crashes will emails be sent twice?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but is sufficiently abstract to be relevant for long enough time.

After using both paradigms I would suggest flat table. It is surprisingly scalable and nifty. Correct hints need to be used.

Once the application goes distributed, or starts using mutiple allways on groups with different RW and RO servers, the Service Broker (or any other method of distributed communication) becomes a neccessity.

### Flat table

- needs only few hints (higly dependent on isolation level) to work scalably and reliably in the *consumer* (READPAST, UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
- the order of message processing is not set in stone
- the consumer must make sure that the message stays in the queue if the processing fails
- needs some polling mechanism (job, CDC (here lies madness :)), external application...)
- turn of maintenance jobs and automatic statistics for the table

### Service broker

- needs extremely overblown "infrastructure" (message types, contracts, services, queues, activation procedures, must be enabled after each server restart, conversations need to be correctly created and dropped...)
- is extremely opaque - we have spent ages trying to make it run after it mysteriously stopped working
- there is a predefined order of message processing
- the tables it uses can cause deadlocks themselfs if SB is overused
- is the only way (except for linked servers...) to send messages directly from database on RW server of one HA group to a database that is RO in this HA group (without any external app)
- is the only way to send messages between different servers (linked servers are a big NONO (unless they become an YESYES - you know the drill - it depends)) (without any external app)